# Issue installing python Mayavi library

Tags: python, python-3.x, mayavi

I am trying to install a library for visualizing density in 3D for some crystallographic applications and teaching resources I would like to make. The library of interest is Mayavi, documentation found here:

When I run pip install mayavi, I get the following error:

```
λ pip install mayavi
Collecting mayavi
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/08/ea/eb808cb4df8f92bc4d9f9a1ef14566b9b5d60370e6ecbaf9061cdae335fa/mayavi-4.7.1.tar.bz2
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\kaneo\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\kaneo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-b2u9s8tf\\mayavi\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\kaneo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-b2u9s8tf\\mayavi\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\kaneo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-b2u9s8tf\mayavi\pip-egg-info'
         cwd: C:\Users\kaneo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-b2u9s8tf\mayavi\
    Complete output (31 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\kaneo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-b2u9s8tf\mayavi\setup.py", line 390, in <module>
        config = configuration().todict()
      File "C:\Users\kaneo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-b2u9s8tf\mayavi\setup.py", line 356, in configuration
        config.add_subpackage('tvtk')
      File "c:\users\kaneo\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 1035, in add_subpackage
        caller_level = 2)
      File "c:\users\kaneo\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 1004, in get_subpackage
        caller_level = caller_level + 1)
      File "c:\users\kaneo\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 941, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
        config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
      File "tvtk\setup.py", line 65, in configuration
        if can_compile_extensions():
      File "tvtk\setup.py", line 27, in can_compile_extensions
        lang='c'
      File "c:\users\kaneo\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils\command\config.py", line 227, in try_compile
        self._compile(body, headers, include_dirs, lang)
      File "c:\users\kaneo\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils\command\config.py", line 133, in _compile
        self.compiler.compile([src], include_dirs=include_dirs)
      File "c:\users\kaneo\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 346, in compile
        self.initialize()
      File "c:\users\kaneo\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 239, in initialize
        vc_env = _get_vc_env(plat_spec)
      File "c:\users\kaneo\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 171, in msvc14_get_vc_env
        return EnvironmentInfo(plat_spec, vc_min_ver=14.0).return_env()
      File "c:\users\kaneo\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 1620, in return_env
        if self.vs_ver >= 14 and isfile(self.VCRuntimeRedist):
      File "c:\users\kaneo\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\genericpath.py", line 30, in isfile
        st = os.stat(path)
    TypeError: stat: path should be string, bytes, os.PathLike or integer, not NoneType
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

I was hoping someone might know how to work through this.
Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Not sure about your problem, but you may want to give [this](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mayavi) a go.

Comment: may I suggest a Mayavi-ready python installation (such as Enthought's Canopy, or Anaconda) or, since you plan on teaching, a cloud-based solution such as Cocalc or [MyBinder](http://mybinder.org/repo/FelipeLema/mne-binder/notebooks/plot_introduction.ipynb). Installing Mayavi is never an easy task.

Comment: Haha -- really! I didn't know it was infamous for being crappy to install.